# How can I get the full instance id using a substring of the deviceid?

Tags: powershell

I was struggling with Powershell and after digging into the internet I could not find my answer. In Powershell, how can I get the list of devices which they have a similar substring in their device ids?

The pseudo-code should be like

```
Get-PnpDevie if(InstanceId includes (USB\234FA))
```

Comment: I would start by ensuring that you use a valid command, please review your submitted command, correct any typos, and ensure that what you are using matches that which you've posted. Additionally, your question is very specifically about powershell.exe, because you've posted PowerShell code, it has nothing whatsoever to do with cmd.exe, so I have removed your invalid [[tag:cmd]] tag. In PowerShell you could get the information like this, `Get-PnPDevice -InstanceId 'USB\234FA*'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the output from `Get-PnpDevice` based on the `InstanceId` property:

```
Get-PnpDevice |Where-Object InstanceId -like '*USB\234FA*'
```

Answer (score -1):

The command given in Mathias Jessen's answer will do the wildcard matching, but in my testing provided a truncated instance ID:

```
>  Get-PnpDevice |Where-Object InstanceId -like '*USB\VID_413C*'

Status     Class           FriendlyName       InstanceId
------     -----           ------------       ----------
Unknown    HIDClass        USB Input Device   USB\VID_413C...
Unknown    HIDClass        USB Input Device   USB\VID_413C...
```

Piping the output to `Format-Table -Autosize` will give the full InstanceID.

```
>  Get-PnpDevice |Where-Object InstanceId -like '*USB\VID_413C*' | Format-Table -Autosize

Status  Class    FriendlyName         InstanceId
------  -----    ------------         ----------
Unknown HIDClass USB Input Device     USB\VID_413C&PID_2113&MI_01\9&E1B9050&0&0001
Unknown HIDClass USB Input Device     USB\VID_413C&PID_2113&MI_00\9&E1B9050&0&0000
```

Credit to this post for using Format-Table to get the full InstanceID:

https://www.tenforums.com/browsers-email/197886-where-do-i-see-all-connected-devices-my-computer-post2463910.html?s=a3f156786469e8a29714bbb93a75dec0#post2463910

Comment: The truncated output is just the display format on the console. The object is always intact when used. I.e. `Get-PnpDevice | where InstanceId -like '*USB\VID_413C*' | select *`